# How to store each iteration of a loop as innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

As a JS novice  I am trying to store all values of an object inside separate divs. (per div the name of the chord and an image).

I get all values logged to the console, but when I store it inside a div I only get the final outcome of the loop, being the last value. In other words: I cant seem to find out how to store the values inside a div for each time the loop runs.

Thank you in forehand!

here the stuff:

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output');

// chords & tabs images

var chords = {
    "C": {
        "Chord" : "C",
        "imgSrc" : "http://www.guitar-chords.org.uk/chord-images/c-major-1.gif"
    },
    "Cmaj9": {
      "Chord" : "Cmaj9",
        "imgSrc" : "http://www.totalguitarandbass.com/system/diagrams/495/original/CMaj9.png?1472445766"
    }
};


// looping through
for(var key in chords) {
    var value = chords[key];
   // log 
   console.log(value);
   // my silly attempt
    output.innerHTML = "<div class=\"chord\">" + "<h1>" + value.Chord + "</h1>" + "<img src=\"" + value.imgSrc + "\"/>";
}
```

```css
div {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display:block;
}
.chord {
  display:block;
  float:left;
  width:250px;
  height:auto;
  border:1px solid tomato;
}

.chord h1 {
  font-size:2.4em;
  text-align:center;
  padding:5px;
}

.chord img {
  display:block;
  margin-top:25px;
  width:200px;
  height:auto;
  padding:25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of what you're trying to do, but you are using `=` instead of `+=`, causing the content to be replaced, not appended.

Comment: wow. overthought the thing way to much. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using = overwrites any prior changes to the property. 
You should use the += operator to append the next element to the innerHTML:

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output');

// chords & tabs images

var chords = {
    "C": {
        "Chord" : "C",
        "imgSrc" : "http://www.guitar-chords.org.uk/chord-images/c-major-1.gif"
    },
    "Cmaj9": {
      "Chord" : "Cmaj9",
        "imgSrc" : "http://www.totalguitarandbass.com/system/diagrams/495/original/CMaj9.png?1472445766"
    }
};


// looping through
for(var key in chords) {
    var value = chords[key];
   // log 
   console.log(value);
   // vvvv Right here vvvvv
    output.innerHTML += "<div class=\"chord\">" + "<h1>" + value.Chord + "</h1>" + "<img src=\"" + value.imgSrc + "\"/>";
}
```

```css
div {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display:block;
}
.chord {
  display:block;
  float:left;
  width:250px;
  height:auto;
  border:1px solid tomato;
}

.chord h1 {
  font-size:2.4em;
  text-align:center;
  padding:5px;
}

.chord img {
  display:block;
  margin-top:25px;
  width:200px;
  height:auto;
  padding:25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/treyeckels/jszzg1oa/

The content of the div is always being replaced by your last line in your `for` loop, which is why the last item in your content array is what's always only displayed.

`innerHTML` is a property of the `output` node that you are retrieving using `getElementById`, so you are writing over the innerHTML of the node every loop.

Instead what you want to do is create new DOM nodes and append them to the last child in the `output` div or if you want to continue to use `innerHTML`, concatenate all of the contents together as a string and then set `output` innerHTML to the concatenated string.

Something like (in es6):

```
const chords = [
    {
        "Chord" : "C",
        "imgSrc" : "http://www.guitar-chords.org.uk/chord-images/c-major-1.gif"
    },
    {
            "Chord" : "Cmaj9",
        "imgSrc" : "http://www.totalguitarandbass.com/system/diagrams/495/original/CMaj9.png?1472445766"
    }
];

const getHTML = (chord, imgSrc) => {
    return(
    `<div class="chord">
        <h1>${chord}</h1>
      <img src="${imgSrc}" />
    </div>`
  )
};

const completeHTML = chords.reduce((prev, next) => {
        return prev + getHTML(next.Chord, next.imgSrc);
}, '');

const output = document.getElementById('output');
output.innerHTML = completeHTML;
```

Comment: This is interesting stuff Trey. Thank you. I’m not able to vote your answer up(yet) so consider this my votu up! Thanks!